# Android JNI: How to see error messages from printf, fprintf and perror?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

This may be a simple problem but I am not able to find a solution.

I am trying to print error messages to figure out errors in my C++ code in JNI. I have calls to printf, fprintf() and perror() but I cannot find where they are being printed.

I have looked inside adb logcat and it is not there (which makes sense). I found a few links that told me to #define LOG... and then use LOG's functions but I would prefer to stick with the initial fprintf and perror.

Is there a way for me to see those messages in an easy way please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, stdout and stderr get send to /dev/null.

A solution I found was to run:

```
adb shell stop
adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
adb shell start
```

from http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

This didn't work for me for some strange reason. I decided to use #define of LOG...

Thanks.